# Find several lowest numbers in a list

Tags: r

After running a function I get of list of 15 integers. I want to pick only those integers that are smaller than 10. 
After that I would just divide the number of integers smaller than 10 by the number of integers greater than 10.
Since there are only 15 integer I can do everything by hand, just input 2/13 for example. But I was wondering if there is a more proper way to do it.

Comment: Where is the reproducible example? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I correctly understood your question, what about something like this?

```
# create dataset:
x <- sample(1:20, 15)
> x
 [1]  1 19  9 18 10  2  4 14 12  6 16  5 15 20  7
# select those < 10
sel <- x < 10
# divide number of integers <10 by those not <10
length(x[sel])/length(x[!sel])
[1] 0.875
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. For some reason didn't thing of simple `<` or `>`. I was thinking in terms of `min()`. But your answer is better

Comment: Glad it worked @AK9309. Please, consider adding next time an example as suggested in the comments (e.g. you could add some code as in my response with what you have tried so far and what your expected output would be). That way people will more easily know what you want. Also, please consider upvoting/accepting answers that are useful to you. Not directly asking for this one, but looking at your post history I assume you are new to the SO model (apologies if you are not). Voting enables other users to find particularly good or useful answers. Thank you.

Comment: My bad, I usually post all of my code. I was just working on the same program for couple hours, and that was the last part and I just couldn't remember how to do it.

Comment: Just recently got the ability to upvote. As you said I am new to SO.
Thanks for your help again